# Save data in DB and upload file using the same API

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I want to save data in DB and upload a file using the same api, I use Angular and Srping :

The problem is I have 2 functions in Angular and 2 functions in Spring, I want to combine them in 1 function Angular and 1 function in Spring. ??

My object is :

```
export class Document {

  id: number;
  title: string;
  file: string;       // file name
  directory: string;
  commandId: number;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  deletedAt: string;
}
```

to save data I use :
Angular :

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
return this.httpClient.post(AppSetting.BASE_URL + AppSetting.DOCUMENTS, document, {headers});
```

Spring :

```
@PostMapping("/")
Document saveDocument(@RequestBody Document document) {
    return docummentService.save(document);
}
```

And to Upload the file I use :
Angular :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('mage', selectedFile, selectedFile.name);

const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
this.httpClient.post(AppSetting.BASE_URL + AppSetting.DOCUMENTS, formData,
        {headers, reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'});
```

Spring :

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        docummentService.uploadFile(file);
        message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }
}
```

Comment: But what's the error? or what's the problem ?

Comment: Please be more specific, on what kind of error are u getting.

Comment: The problem is I have 2 functions in Angular and 2 functions in Spring, I want to combine them in 1 function Angular and 1 function in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipartFile as a transient field in your document class. After that you get all the document details and the file both. Now you can upload the file and save the document details in a single API.